# .exe triggers breakpoint while using ofstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to write a program that creates an output .txt file.

When it's running, I get an ".exe has triggered a breakpoint" message in VS 2019 after a certain amount of signs. I tried to reproduce that error in another project, but wasn't able to. However, I managed to pin it down in the original project.

What I'm basically doing is:

```
ofstream file;
file.open("Test.txt", ios::app);

for(int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    file << 1;

file.close();
```

The breakpoint triggers on different powers of 2, depending on how I write into the file.

`file << 1` triggers after 4 096, `file << to_string(1)` after 8 192 and `file << to_string(11)` after 16 384. `file << "1"` causes no issues.

Using a `stringstream` instead of an `ofstream` or appending a normal `string` leads to pretty much the same results.

Stopping the debugger leaves the file with exactly that amount of characters. Continuing will keep on writing and leaves the file with the intended 500 000 characters.

VS doesn't seem to have any other problems.

The original project is an MFC-Application, but I changed an onBnClicked-function to the code I provided.

Creating another MFC-Application with only one button which does that works.

Because there is no real error description I'm pretty confused about what's happening there...

---

Edit:
I created a new project and included all the files again and it works now.

Comment: What is the call stack when you encounter the error? Is it somewhere in the memory manager, perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.